# WooCommerce order_items in order table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

Could someone help me to list all the items a customer ordered instead the orders.
And also to add meta data as an extra column to the list.

Like shown in the image below:

[image]

This is the template that I should override:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/dbb6e2716d16625aab4868e6396176ccbdb040dd/templates/myaccount/orders.php

I believe I should do something with the following information:

```
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) { 
   $name = $item->get_name();
   $somemeta = $item->get_meta( 'my_meta', true );
}
```

Comment: To show the products name you could use [Show products name and quantity in a new column on Woocommerce My account Orders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55551700/11987538). To display the product images instead you could use [How to insert the first 3 product images of an order in WooCommerce “My account” orders table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63093913/11987538). Furthermore your question lacks some focus, what do you mean by add metadata? 
An order contains a lot of data, which data is it specifically about?

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot.
About the meta data, I will start a new topic to clearify.